# Does a hidden Yeld spyrer block line of sight?

Tags: necromunda

A Yeld spyrer can hide in the open thanks to their chameleon wings. Does this block line of sight to models behind? What I want to do is place another spyrer behind the hiding Yeld so that they can't be targeted.

I play the 1st edition, but happy to see answers from LRB.